# sendmail doesn't send mail, with no errors

Tags: sendmail

I have trouble with sendmail 8.15 on Debian 11.
It doesn't send mail but /var/log/mail.err is empty
/var/log/mail.log

```
Oct  7 09:27:54 debian11 sendmail[2961]: 1977Rg4D002961: from=andrea, size=37, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202110070727.1977Rg4D002961@localhost.station>, relay=root@localhost
Oct  7 09:27:54 debian11 sm-mta[2962]: 1977RsRh002962: from=<andrea@localhost.station>, size=337, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<202110070727.1977Rg4D002961@localhost.station>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Oct  7 09:27:54 debian11 sendmail[2961]: 1977Rg4D002961: to=andreadicioccio@gmail.com, ctladdr=andrea (1000/1000), delay=00:00:12, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30037, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (1977RsRh002962 Message accepted for delivery)
```

I followed https://www.cloudbooklet.com/how-to-install-and-setup-sendmail-on-debian-10
do you have any suggestions?
thanks

Comment: Based on [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50685412), have you checked your Gmail spam folder?

Comment: @Haxiel yes, sure, there isn't email in spam folder

Comment: It's handed off to the local mta and it's not doing anything with it. You have set `define(`SMART_HOST',`[smtp-host]')dnl` correctly? If I were you, I'd use `postfix`...

Comment: @Bib thanks for reply, i don't know, i disinstalled it and used msmtp, it works